# run flask application using google compute engine

Tags: python-2.7, flask, google-compute-engine

I'm new to flask and google compute engine.

when i'm running my flask application on google compute engine , using curl I can see my flask methods are running.

I want to see the web page which flask is using, the problem is when I'm running my flask the http url is http://127.0.0.1:5000 and when I use the link to see webpage it will show nothing I have tried my external ip of google compute engine so my link is 
`http://<external-ip-address-of google-compute-engine>:5000` but still is not working.

Please let me know how to set localhost of google compute engine to my google compute engine external ip. I have config my static ip for google compute engine instance.

I'm using linux 14.04LTS

please give me suggestions to solve the issue.

Answer (score 4):

finally I'm able to get the solution of the question I have asked.

Follow the Link : http://www.datasciencebytes.com/bytes/2015/02/24/running-a-flask-app-on-aws-ec2/

Somehow my question is also misleading as I'm not aware about the proper terminology. My question is all about to set up flask deployment environment on wsgi mode.